# I am not getting data in PDF download when i export primefaces table using p:dataExporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using the data Exporter , I am not getting the content from table ,instead i am getting error

**javax.faces.component .html.HtmlPanelGroup @f41a16** please find the The code below which i used for pdf download

```
  <h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage name="../../images/pdf.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="QuantityDeviationTable" fileName="QuantityDeviationTable" pageOnly="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: [mcve] please. The error cannot be caused by just the code you posted

Comment: My advise is to see the example provided in [Primefaces DataExporter](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml), in case it doesn't work add the log.